# Add and remove a basename suffix to all files in Windows directory structure

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I have a directory with subdirectories, containing around two hundred data files.

Example

```
|
+---FOLDER
|   |   FILEA.DAT
|   |   FILEB.DAT
|   |
|   +---SUBFOLDER
|   |       FILEA.DAT
|   |       FILEB.DAT
|   |
```

I need a batch file to rename all files in the current folder and sub folders to
`<originalfilename>_1.ext`. This is done by batch file `b1.bat`, (so I replace whatever files I need).

The batch File 1 is:

```bash
@echo off
cd C:\Users\user123\ERPTEST\
ren *.* *_1.*
```

It renames the extension, not the filename, and the batch file, `b1.bat`, which is in the same directory.

I run the test by replacing one or two files. When the bug is fixed, I delete my test files,
and restore the files back to the original name, `<originalfilename>_1.ext` to `<originalfilename>.ext` in batch two.

batch two is:

```bash
@echo off
cd C:\Users\user123\ERPTEST\
for %I in (*_1.*) do rename "%~nI.*" "%~nI"
for %I in (*_1.*) do rename "%~nI_1.*" "%~nI.pdf"
```

But this does not seem to work.

Ideas?

Comment: You need a `For /F` loop. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage and help information. Please read and understand all of the output, it contains everything you need to achieve this task.

Comment: Why not simply `xcopy /s/e "...erptext\*" "saveerp\"`? you then have a copy of the entire tree in `saveerp` and can copy it back anytime. Similarly, you could use a utility like `7z` to store a copy of the entire tree to a single file, or restore the tree from that single file?